# Commit uncommited code from old svn repository to new svn repository

Tags: svn, netbeans, repository

I have some uncommited code from old svn repository which is down now. I want to commit this code to new svn repository. I have taken the project backup from old svn.
How can I commit the code to new svn?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`svn import`](https://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svn.c.import.html) command if the backup you have is an export of repository tree from your repository (i.e., the most recent snapshot of data). If you have a working copy with the hidden `.svn` directory in its root, then make sure that you don't commit this directory into your new repository. This is a local metadata directory and you should not commit it into a repo.

If you have any other type of backup which you want to import, then it makes sense to update your question with more details.

See the documentation:

- [Subversion Quick Start](https://subversion.apache.org/quick-start#importing-data)
- [SVNBook | Getting Data into Your
  Repository](https://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.tour.importing.html)
- [TortoiseSVN Manual | Importing Data Into A
  Repository](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-import.html)